Eigenvalue of Legendre ODE.
Given the boundary conditions that
$$-1<x<1$$
$$y(0)=0$$
$$y'(0)=0$$
Is there any way to solve the following differential equation:
$$(1-x^2)y^{"}-2xy'+{\lambda}y=0$$
I know this equation can be solved using series method. But It is quite arduous to find the eigenvalue. Is there any other possible way to find the eigenvalues of this equation or this is the only way available?

Should $1 < x < 1$ be $-1 < x < 1$?

@KyleKnoepfel corrected.

This is just the ODE for Legendre polynomials.  The fact that you are looking for eigenvalues indicates that the solution for $y$ is decomposed into a series of eigenfunctions.  In other words, you can't have the eigenvalues without a series expansion of the Legendre polynomials.  So I think the short answer is, no, you cannot obtain the eigenvalues without the series.
